# sed extract text between two patterns where second pattern may be either of one

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I am trying to extract text between pattern1 (fixed) and pattern2 (this can be p2-1/p2-2).
can you please tell me how to achieve this in a single command?

A file starts with `start` and ends with either `end` or `close`

```
File1:
======
junktest
data
start
stackoverflow
sed
close

File2:
======
data2
start
stackoverflow
end
```

I can extract text from File1 with

```
sed -n "/start/,/close/p"
```

And from File2 with

```
sed -n "/start/,/end/p"
```

I need a single sed command to achieve both..
something like:

```
sed -n "/start/, /close or end /p"
```

Comment: Print both files at once or two pattern spaces?

Comment: Actually I just made it as two files..
But I get some output from a command, I have to extract text between two patterns from the output.. Start Pattern is fixed..But the end format can be one of Two(fixed).
Is there any way I can specify that in sed command

Comment: Ah, try using `|` which specifies an "or" as such `sed -n "/start/,/close|end/p"`

Comment: Nope, that does not seem to be working!

Comment: I tried sed -n "/start/,/close|end/p" and sed -n "/start/,/close\|end/p"

Comment: Try (close|end).  What version of sed do you have?

Comment: No, does not work. FreeBSD 7.1 version.

Comment: BSD sed is different.  Maybe try adding a -E to your command for the pipe character. It is for extended regular expressions.

Comment: sed -n -E "/Word1/,/Word2-1/p" | sed -n -E "/Word1/,/Word2-2/p" 
Thanks for the help @squiguy

Comment: So you got it to work?  I would suggest closing your question or answering it yourself.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 5):

Both GNU `sed` and BSD `sed`:

```
sed -nE '/start/,/close|end/p' file
```

Comment: As an OS X user, I always have problems with `sed` answers, so thank you so much for testing in BSD!

Answer (score 2):

This awk looks better

```
awk '/start/,/end|close/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n -E "/Word1/,/Word2-1/p" | sed -n -E "/Word1/,/Word2-2/p"
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/start/{p=1}p{print}/end|close/{p=0}' file
```